# How to change Status Bar (Style / Color) of UISplitViewController iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uistatusbar

i am trying to change the status Bar Style of `UISplitViewController`

i used to do that with `UINavigationBar`

`UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black`

but the `UISplitViewController` does not have an `appearance` property

is there anyway to change that Style ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

View controller-based status bar appearance is set to `YES` by default. So you just have to subclass your split controller like

```
class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController {

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.BlackOpaque
    }

}
```

Comment: is there really no way to just set the statusBar style via the plist?  How is this still a thing in iOS 10 and Xcode 8??

Comment: @whyoz, just use SplitView instead :)